# Cannot set read-only property

Tags: php, properties, readonly

Are there actually read-only properties in PHP and I'm not aware of them? How do I get a public property to be read-only??

I was just playing with ReflectionClass and I got this error message when trying to overwrite a property:

```
$lol = new ReflectionObject($obj);
$lol->name = 'awawawawa';
```

Comment: Uh! Properties don't work like that: they're either private, protected or public... though you can simulate it with magic getters and setters

Comment: I know, and I'm using getters for exactly this purpose :( But what does ReflectionClass use to make them read only??? Obviously they are not getters because they wouldn't appear there...

Comment: Well the ReflectionObject isn't another instance of $obj, or a pointer to it, so it doesn't have the same methods... it's a ReflectionObject which has its own unique properties and methods that can be used to display information about $obj. The ReflectionObject doesn't have a property (public or otherwise) called "name", even if $obj does, so you can't change that value. I'm assuming that Reflection implements magic getters/setters in its own way to prevent just this

Comment: @MarkBaker in fact, it has a public property called name. it is documented. `ReflectionObject extends ReflectionClass` and `ReflectionClass` containts `public $ReflectionClass->name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP Manual Page for ReflectionObject:

```
Properties

name

    Name of the object's class. Read-only, throws ReflectionException in attempt to write.
```

http://sk.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php

There isn't much on **how** they do this, but my guess would be that it's explicitly looking out for the writing of the name property and stopping it from happening as it would make the reflection a lie.

You could do something similar yourself:

```
<?php
class MyReadOnlyJunk
{
    protected // over private, or not defined here at all
        $name = 'My Name';

    public function __set($key, $val)
    {
        if($key == 'name')
            throw new Exception('Cannot has name set!');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't think that works, because the property exists so __set will never fire...

Comment: Yes sorry, it works if it's not public or doesn't exist (though member methods may be able to set it still unless it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 3):

From the code of the reflection class:

```
/* {{{ _reflection_write_property */
static void _reflection_write_property(zval *object, zval *member, zval *value TSRMLS_DC)
{
    if ((Z_TYPE_P(member) == IS_STRING)
        && zend_hash_exists(&Z_OBJCE_P(object)->default_properties, Z_STRVAL_P(member), Z_STRLEN_P(member)+1)
        && ((Z_STRLEN_P(member) == sizeof("name") - 1  && !memcmp(Z_STRVAL_P(member), "name",  sizeof("name")))
            || (Z_STRLEN_P(member) == sizeof("class") - 1 && !memcmp(Z_STRVAL_P(member), "class", sizeof("class")))))
    {
        zend_throw_exception_ex(reflection_exception_ptr, 0 TSRMLS_CC, 
            "Cannot set read-only property %s::$%s", Z_OBJCE_P(object)->name, Z_STRVAL_P(member));
    }
    else
    {
        zend_std_obj_handlers->write_property(object, member, value TSRMLS_CC);     
    }
}
/* }}} */
```

so basically, it's explicitly forbidding it for the "name" and "class" properties.
I can't find any indication that a class property exists though!

Answer (score 1):

[PHP docs](http://php.net/reflectionclass):

> Name of the object's class. Read-only, throws ReflectionException in attempt to write.

I don't see anything in the `Properties` page about making things read-only, though... I guess possibly prefix them with `final`, but I don't know if that's allowed since it's only mentioned on methods.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php):

> **Properties**
>   *name*
>       Name of the class. Read-only, throws ReflectionException in attempt to write.

However, the docs also say

```
ReflectionClass implements Reflector {
  /* Properties */
  public $ReflectionClass->name;
  ...
```

It is important to note here, that (even if the documentation looks ReflectionClass is implemented in pure PHP) the ReflectionClass is part of the **PHP core**, thus implemented in C!

Although the property is *documented* as being a normal public property, in fact its not!

I'm too lazy to dig into the PHP source code for this, but you will find a special case handling there which protects the public property making it read-only. EDIT: see Mark Bakers answer.